# How to load data into dynamodb table from the reducer of a hadoop job

Tags: java, hadoop, amazon-web-services, mapreduce, amazon-dynamodb

I was unsuccessful in finding a sample mapreduce job to write data to dynamoDB. Any references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `hive` is a possible solution for you, you can look here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMR_Hive_Commands.html

It's pretty straight forward if you use tools like `PIG` and `hive` - just declare your input table as `S3` (or whatever), your output table as a `DynamoDB` one, and perform `INSERT TABLE X SELECT * FROM Y`

Comment: Hey found it. There is  a way to upload using dynamodb java API. I have used put request and it worked. Thanks.